# Can a Windows Forms Framework (4.8) App execute on Windows 10 IOT Enterprise?

Tags: winforms, frameworks, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I have developed a .NET Framework WinForms app that was developed to run on a Windows 7 Pro computer. The customer is needing to add BLE 5.0 capability to the tester, which looks like it will require Windows 10.

I may be able to purchase a computer with the Windows 10 IOT Enterprise operating system. I need to verify whether or not a WinForms Framework app will work on this operating system prior to purchasing it.

I have seen in the website, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot, that Windows 10 IOT Enterprise supports WinForms, but it does not indicate if it supports WinForms Framework, or only WinForms Core.

Can someone point me to a definitive answer to this question?

I have not been able to test a WinForms Framework app on Windows 10 IOT Enterprise because I do not have access to a computer with that operating system installed.